# How to access the vertices of several paths in Gremlin through Java?

Tags: java, gremlin

I'm new in Gremlin and Java.  I wish find two shortest paths. Each path must be unique/distinct and independent of each other. 
I tried

- "`dedup()`" but its works on global path and not on vertices that constitute the path.
- "`limit(2)`" of course but paths are not independent (some vertices are present in the two paths)

I don't known if it's possible to make this with gremlin.

this is my code:

```
List<Object> result = g.V().has("name", "room1").as("from").repeat(out().simplePath())
            .until(has("name", "room2")).as("to").path().as("p").select("p").limit(2).toList();
```

Have you suggestion in Gremlin ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample graph and the expected output? I'm not sure about your definition of uniqueness; you want both paths to start and end at the same vertices, but still not share any vertices? You mean no shared vertices, except the start and end vertex?

Comment: For example, I have a graph with 5 vertices noted d0 to d4. There are three paths possible between d0 and d3: d0 ->d1 ->d2->d3, d0 -> d1 -> d4 -> d3 and d0 ->d4->d3. Paths must begin at the same vertice (d0) and finish at the same vertice (d3). I want find 2 independant shortest path i.e. d0->d4->d3, d0 ->d1->d2->d3.

Answer (score 0):

The sample graph from your comment:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV().property(id, 'd0').
  addV().property(id, 'd1').
  addV().property(id, 'd2').
  addV().property(id, 'd3').
  addV().property(id, 'd4').
  addV().property(id, 'd5').
  addE('link').from(V('d0')).to(V('d1')).
  addE('link').from(V('d0')).to(V('d4')).
  addE('link').from(V('d1')).to(V('d2')).
  addE('link').from(V('d1')).to(V('d4')).
  addE('link').from(V('d2')).to(V('d3')).
  addE('link').from(V('d4')).to(V('d3')).iterate()
```

All paths from `d0` to `d3`:

```
gremlin> g.V('d0').
......1>   repeat(out('link').simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasId('d3')).
......3>   path()
==>[v[d0],v[d4],v[d3]]
==>[v[d0],v[d1],v[d2],v[d3]]
==>[v[d0],v[d1],v[d4],v[d3]]
```

Now to filter paths based on which vertices have already been seen between the start- and end-vertex, you just have to memorize those vertices and use them as a filter for further vertices:

```
gremlin> g.V('d0').
......1>   repeat(out('link').simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasId('d3')).
......3>   path().
......4>   filter(unfold().hasId(without('d0','d3')).fold().
......5>          filter(unfold().where(without('x'))).
......6>          unfold().store('x'))
==>[v[d0],v[d4],v[d3]]
==>[v[d0],v[d1],v[d2],v[d3]]
```

Comment: it's work in gremlin console but when I tried in java, the result is not the same. the gremlin request gives all paths.  I have the impression that the filter does not work.